# CONDITION ERROR: 'If not' condition does not run leading to variables within that condition not being defined

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a piece of code which reads in a file, assigns each line to variable 's', and evaluates whether the 'activity' column of each line of that file contains 'substr_neg', which is assigned to a '-' character.

If this character is true, then I fulfil the conditions and call a function to the 'name' column of that same line.

If false, I go to the next line.

(Just to clarify, this conditional statement is meant to see if characters in substr_neg is present in 'ss', if it is, then 'do something', else,  go to next line in that file).

However, the problem is, is that the 'if not' statement conditions do not appear to be fulfilled, hence variable 'v' does not get assigned to the result of function 'foofoo'.

Also:

```
if not(foo)
```

is meant to represent a function which searches whether a string value already exists within the text file, if not, it applies the function to the name column of the file.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the conditions of the 'if not' statement are not being fulfilled? Perhaps scope reasons? Removing the

```
if (char in substr_neg for char in ss):
```

along with the elif statement solves all problems...but obviously this is not what I am looking for.

```
substr_neg ='-'
var = 'str'
char = ''
with open("file.txt") as file: 
    for lines in file:
        if not lines.startswith("#"):
            s = lines
            ss = s.split('\t')
            if (char in substr_neg for char in ss):
                name = ss[0];
                activity = ss[2];
                varvar ="str".format(var, 
                name)
            else:
                next(file)
                if not foo(varvar):
                    v = foofoo(name)
                    foofoofoo(v)
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The file variable is not a List, to turn it to a List:

```py
   file_list = file.readlines()
   #Then loop through file_list
   for lines in file_list:
       #...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but this still does not work. I still get a NameError for the variable 'v'.

Comment: @cheesesandwich The remaining issue is from your else statement, you are referencing variables name and varvar that doesn't exist..... Because the if statement wasn't satisfied they don't exist and that was why the code under the else: was ran in the first place. Hope this helps

Comment: Both name and varvar do exist. When I call them, they are defined, it's just 'v' that does not exist.

Comment: If name and varvar exist, then the problem is not from this code here, most probably from the method foofoo